# SQL: View Full Name From User ID (Send To / Send From)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

**Students**

```
StudentID     UserID     FirstName     LastName
1             1          John          Doe
2             3          Peter         Pan
3             5          Mark          Twain
```

**Employees**

```
EmployeeID     UserID     FirstName     LastName
1              2          Juan          Carlos
2              4          Joe           Reyes
3              6          Ash           Ketchum
```

**Users**

```
UserID     Username
1          test1
2          test2
3          test3
4          test4
5          test5
6          test6
```

**Messages**

```
MessageID     MessageFrom     MessageTo     Subject
1             1               2             test message
2             4               3             another test message
3             3               5             another test message
```

I want to display the output like this

```
MessageID     MessageFrom     MessageTo     Subject
1             John Doe        Juan Carlos   test message
2             Joe Reyes       Peter Pan     another test message
3             Peter Pan       Mark Twain    another test message
```

Where `MessageFrom` and `MessageTo` returns a foreign key value from `UserID` located from the Users table. Students can send messages to the employees, and vice-versa. They can also send between students and employees.

Comment: There seems to be a little problem with your structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, since you don't care if the message is related to a student or employee you can just union those 2 tables.

```
SELECT 
    MessageID,
    (FromTable.FirstName + ' ' + FromTable.LastName) AS MessageFrom,
    (ToTable.FristName + ' ' + ToTable.LastName) AS MessageTo,
    Subject
FROM
    Messages
    INNER JOIN
    (
        (SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName FROM Students)
        UNION 
        (SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName FROM Employees)
    ) AS FromTable ON FromTable.UserID = Messages.MessageFrom
    INNER JOIN
    (
        (SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName FROM Students)
        UNION 
        (SELECT UserID, FirstName, LastName FROM Employees)
    ) AS ToTable ON ToTable.UserID = Messages.MessageTo
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is [The X Y Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) again.

Why did you split your `Users` in two parts ?

Why not making it like this (which would solve the whole problem) :

```
UserID  |   FirstName   |  LastName | UserName |  Type
-------------------------------------------------------
  1           John          Doe        test1       1
  2           Juan          Carlos     test2       2
  3           Mark          Twain      test3       1
```

And add a table Types

```
TypeId  |   TypeName
```

---

```
  1          Students
  2          Employees
```

This way you have 2 Tables for users instead of 3. 
All users and names are in the same table as [it should be](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm).

Comment: I would agree that this is a much better structure, however baring the ability to alter the schema, the OP can still query the data they need.

Comment: Yes I just read your query and it would work. But still I think database normalization is the first step. A good structure keeps you from having nightmarish querys and problems. But you're right if the OP can't change the structure he will have to use your query

Comment: What's more, the username does not need to be a separate table, there is no reason that it would violate normal form to have them with the other values.

Comment: The only issue I could see with going to this structure is if there is some reason why the StudentID space and the EmployeeID space should not be the same.  Your solution does drop a column, but it might be unnecessary for the OP's implementation.

Comment: True although it is not stated or explained that it is important so I voted for wrong structure. OP will tell us I guess

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: StudentID and EmployeeID have different increment seeds because they don't have the same ID structure. That's why I separated them.

Comment: Isn't that simply because of the way you structured it ? If they are in the same table, what would be the Id problem ?

Comment: @StefanH: I didn't include the other column names from the Users table.

Comment: @eibhrum Gotcha - that makes sense - I was not proposing a schema change anyways :)